# How does a Bitcoin wallet app find unspent transaction outputs?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

Can we say the Bitcoin wallet applications (at least some) behave as Simplified Payment Verification(SPV) nodes?

How does the wallet application find the corresponding user's unspent transaction outputs, while creating a new transaction (to be included into the new transaction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPV will query full nodes using a Bloom filter to retrieve those transactions: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#bloom-filters